# Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table

Tags: email, postfix, postgresql

I am setting up a Mail Server using Postfix and Dovecot. Sending Mail works perfectly fine but receiving it doesn't work. When I use my GMail account to send emails t myself, I get this error:
`Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table`

My users are stored in a PostgreSQL table.

Here is my main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-aliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-mailbox.cf
alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-aliases.cf
#alias_database = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-aliases.cf
#local_recipient_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-mailbox.cf
local_recipient_maps = 
myorigin = mydomain.com
mydestination = mydomain.com, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
#mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = mydomain.com
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
```

pgsql-virtual-aliases.cf:

```
hosts = localhost
user = postfix
password = my_password
dbname = my_db

query = SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '%s'
```

pgsql-virtual-mailbox.cf:

```
hosts = localhost
user = postfix
password = my_password
dbname = my_db

query = SELECT concat(email,'/') as email FROM users WHERE username='%u'
```

Answer (score -2):

In case you have virtual alias map set correctly, just remove this line from your main.cf config:

myorigin = mydomain.com

the advice is from here: https://www.virtualmin.com/node/7746
I lost a ton of time trying to figure out why virtual users were not found.

Comment: How is this supposed to help?

Comment: Look at the URL I added above.

Comment: This actually helped me in the context of a missconfig with virtualmin.